# TIFF file has weird meta information specifically in image size

Tags: python, opencv, png, tiff, libtiff

I have some tiff image files which have multiple pages in one tiff file.

I tried to make separated image files by reading image meta information with libtiff and some python libraries, but the image size seems **weird**.

Below is the description of a page by using tiffinfo.

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x67ca (26570)
  Image Width: 1728 Image Length: 1131
  Resolution: 204, 98 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 1
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-white
  FillOrder: lsb-to-msb
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 1131
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Page Number: 0-8
  ImageDescription: 0512464945
```

But actually, if I see this image with image viewer(for me, I use just default Windows Image viewer program) has a longer height than width.

[image]

Whenever I changed this image as a separated TIFF image, it just looks the same as an original TIF file.

But when I changed this image as PNG, it shrank and looks like the size is changed.

[image]

This problem happens regardless of the compression method like LZW or CCITT or python library such as OpenCV, pillow, tiffimage, etc.

Why this is so different? and how can I adjust this image size when converting PNG format?

Sorry for the bad sample images due to the personal information in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Resolution: 204, 98 pixels/inch
```

that is the piece of information you need to incorporate.

```
Image Width: 1728 Image Length: 1131

>>> 1728 / 204, 1131 / 98
(8.47, 11.54) # inches
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just got some idea from your comment. I just resize my image file with a smaller resolution. like 1728 / 204 * 98 -> 803 to be real width size. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: if you feel that my answer solves your problem, feel encouraged to accept it as such and/or give it a vote.